# LWC Component when deployed to source not showing the updated UI

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have the below code which does not match with what I see in the UI. When deploying the source to the org I see the status as success but I dont see the changes in the UI.

```
 <template lwc:if={availablePartsList}>
        <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Selected Part" >
            <lightning-layout multiple-rows="false">
                <template for:each={availablePartsList} for:item="part">
                <div key={part.Id}>
                <lightning-layout-item size="9" >
                    <p>{part.Name}</p>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item size="3">
                    Test
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout>
     </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

As you can see the title of the lightning card is **Selected Part** but on the UI I still see it as **Selected Parts**. I have read somewhere this is something related to caching.
[image]

These are settings I changed on my sandbox org -

1. Session Settings - Unchecked **Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance**
2. Turned on **Debug Mode** for myself.
3. Also changed the sfdx deploy mode using this command - **sfdx config:set restDeploy=false**

Also want to mention that I am using this LWC component inside of a flow and I am testing it using the debug button of the flow.

Please advise as this is blocking me from proceeding.

Comment: You didn't mention this, but did you try refreshing the flow builder window after deploying the component? Does your component implement the correct target attributes for displaying in a flow screen?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira yes I did refresh the flow builder window. It does implement the correct target attributes. I see this issue as intermittent. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Could someone help out please?